# How to install external library from source for cmake to find it?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, libraries, dependency-management

Say I am writing a library `my_project` that uses some other library `dependency_lib`.
What I'm currently doing during development is: I've cloned the code of the dependency to some normal, human accessible directory in my file system. I've built that library according to the instructions from its developers, and now I have a shared library `dependency_lib.so` somewhere in that directory.
Then in my `CMakeLists.txt` I have:

```
find_library(DEPENDENCY_LIB dependency_lib HINTS /home/my_name/Documents/path/to/the/built/dependency/lib)
target_link_libraries(my_project PRIVATE ${DEPENDENCY_LIB})
```

This works great for me, but obviously when other people clone my code and try to build it, they will have that external library at some other location on their system, so this won't work for them.

1. Is there some standard location to put built libraries in for cmake to find them, where I can assume other developers also put their built libraries in?
2. Is it even reasonable for me to expect other developers/users of my library to also clone the source code of the dependency and build it, or is there some other solution for external dependencies on C++?
   Any comments, explanations and resources on dependency management with cmake are very appreciated.

Bonus question: Why can't this be as simple as Python with `pip`, Rust with `cargo` or JavaScript with `npm`?

Comment: For #2 Many projects do require you to obtain all of the dependencies yourself.

Comment: You could use this: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/module/ExternalProject.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.22/module/ExternalProject.html) to download and build the dependency with your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly, developers add SDKs folder to let others use the required SDKs. It may be because they did minor/major changes inside the library and it became a custom build version and special for them. So, it means,  they have to pack it inside the project since others can't find the modified version of that library. And I think, this is what you're looking for:

```
find_package(Library ${LIB_VERSION} EXACT REQUIRED PATHS "${LIB_DIR}")
```

By declaring `PATHS` you can have `CMake` look for the libraries specific directories.

Comment: This means having the dependency library as a git submodule, and a cmake subdirectory, and adding to it a `Find<PackageName>.cmake` file, and building it together with my project, right? It's nice that other devs or users don't need to clone and build dependencies on their own, just `init` and `update` git submodules, but in the `ExternalProject` approach suggested by @drescherjm they might not even have to do that if I understand correctly.

Comment: Yes. Additionally, most of the libraries contain '.cmake' files that helps CMake to determine the version, library directories and etc. 
If it's not obvious enough, feel free to ask. And if it solves your problem, don't forget to mark as solved.